# iPhone iOS UITableView(about asynchronous request download image)

Tags: iphone, ios

I meet some strange problem, I hope you can help me or give me some ideas.
I am trying to use `uitableview` to display some products which includes some text and one image in each cell. I use [ASIHTTPRequest framework](http://allseeing-i.com/ASIHTTPRequest/) to try to asynchronous download image for each cell.

I also made one refresh button on the the screen, every time if click this button it will send a request to re-download and reload everything in `tableview`.

My problem is: when program start running normally, it can display everything right. But if I keep clicking the refresh button continually, even when the last requests is not finish. The program crash and it will give following error:

> In ASIHTTPRequest.m file at about line:3183  [self
>   handleBytesAvailable];
>       said: Thread 8: program received signal:"EXC_BAD_ACCESS"

All my program I just follow by one [github project](https://github.com/akosma/async-uitableview).
After doing some testing for this demo project, I find the same problem.

Can any people tell me how to fix these problem? 
And If I don't want to use ASIHTTPRequest framework what is the best way (stable and efficient) to implement asynchronous download image from different resource.

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

Although *ASIHTTPRequest* is a powerful tool, I prefer using *HJCache* for fetching images from the web in UITableView. So if you are able to switch your framework I recommend *HJCache*. The source is [here](https://github.com/markofjohnson/HJCache) and the article about this is [here](http://www.markj.net/hjcache-iphone-image-cache/). The project includes also a simple demo that fetches images from the web and displays it in the UITableView. It supports caching, so it's really cool.

> HJCache is library for asynchronous download of images and other data
>   over the net, and for sharing  and caching them. Its for iPhone / iOS,
>   it works with data other than images too, and its free. The library is
>   designed to make it easy to make fast scrolling table views (for
>   example) that contain imaged loaded from URLs. Eg a twitter app that
>   shows the profile pic for each post in each table cell.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help. I will have a look and try this new framework.